# Any way to simply this javascript function any further?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

Here's the code I want to simplify further if possible (I got a whole list of ifs but this should give you a general idea of what I want):

```
function doc(type, name) {
    if (type === 'getid')return document.getElementById(name);
    if (type === 'getclass')return document.getElementsByClassName(name);
}
```

Comment: This might be better received at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but it's pretty basic.

Comment: Looks pretty simple to me.  What do you think is wrong with it?  What about it is complex or difficult to understand?  How do you *use* this function?  And can the whole thing be replaced with `document.querySelectorAll`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: A selector is already a string that specifies a dom lookup on a particular characteristic, i.e `"." + name` is a selector for class name, `#` for id and so on, perhaps adapt to that using querySelector*.

Comment: i was planning on adding `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode`, etc. so `document.querySelectorAll` wouldnt work

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with the types as key and the methods as values.

```
function doc(type, name) {
    return document[{
        getid: 'getElementById',
        getclass: 'getElementsByClassName'
    }[type]](name);
}
```

Comment: What if `type` is something other than `'getid'` or `'getclass'`?

Comment: you could add a default value if `type` is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could use a `switch` statement. For example:

```
function doc(type, name) {
    var element;
    switch(type) {
        case 'getid':
            element = document.getElementById(name);
            break;
        case 'getclass':
            element = document.getElementsByClassName(name);
            break;
    }
    return element;
}
```